# Symfony ServiceSubscriber aliased service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

In Symfony you can DI a different services with the same interface as followed:

```php
public function __construct(ServiceInterface $serviceOne, ServiceInterface $serviceTwo)
```

But how can this be achieved the same way with the `ServiceSubscriberInterface`?

```php
public static function getSubscribedServices()
{
    return [
        'commandBus' => MessageBusInterface::class . ' $commandBus',
        'queryBus' => MessageBusInterface::class . '$queryBus',
    ];
}
```

These are the resources I already checked:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger/multiple_buses.html

Comment: your first statement is slightly wrong, this is quite rarely the case and as far as I can tell specific for the messenger component, that it cares for the var name. This is also the reason, why I assume, this is not as simple with the `ServiceSubscriberInterface`. However, I assume you have a specific use case, and maybe that use case can be solved, if you would provide at least some details about it.

Comment: In the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger/multiple_buses.html) they show how you can DI $queryBus and $commandBus with the same MessageBusInterface. So I assumed you can also use it with the Service Locator.

Comment: yes, but that's done in a special compiler pass in the messenger component. there is no compiler pass that handles ServiceSubscriberInterfaces for this specific case. It would really help if you describe what the use case is, because there are lots of use cases and most of them have different approaches.

Comment: Ahhaa! My use case is that I have an abstract handler that needs couple of services and the child can (optionally) include services it needs. I liked [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#including-services) pattern.

Comment: I thought that the ServiceSubscriberInterface used the same container to fetch the services? Services with ServiceSubscriberInterface are lazily loaded therefor the used container should have the compiled $queryBus and $commandBus from the Messenger compiler pass. Right?

Comment: I just realized, I might be wrong ... maybe you just need to drop the keys of your array .......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200751/discussion-between-jakumi-and-snek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of testing and with @Jakumi's help. Found out that the array key can be used to resolve the aliased service, as followed.

```php
public static function getSubscribedServices()
{
    return [
       'commandBus' => MessageBusInterface::class,
       'queryBus' => MessageBusInterface::class,
    ];
}
```

In my messenger.yaml:

```
framework:
  messenger:
    default_bus: 'command.bus'
    buses:
      command.bus:
        // stuff
      query.bus:
        // stuff
```

Comment: I wonder ... shouldn't it be `'command.bus'` and `'query.bus'` in the `getSubscribedServices` too?

Comment: Nope. Because the compiler pass of the messenger makes them camel case. [See screenshot](https://prnt.sc/pj4tfv)

Comment: that's suprisingly unintuitive... thank you for your time ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I was doubtful, but apparently you're right and you can use an interface multiple times, but there has to be done some [work](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type), essentially the messenger component will do stuff like this, I guess (I've not checked extensively - update: I tried to find this, but been unsuccessful so far ...).

That's why I assume the constructor DI works. The ServiceSubscriberInterface::getSubscribedServices() is [used in a similar way](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/4edbbc4c279ac91ee09a3ae8c285a7592afe8868/Compiler/RegisterServiceSubscribersPass.php#L81): 
specifically, the **key** of that array is assumed to be an alias or the class name or the interface name or ... but apparently, it's not to give you a nice way to index your array of services, because it has meaning.

So, I would assume, that just removing the keys of your array there might very well do the job. Alternatively, you might use the actual service name of the `MessageBusInterface`s, by running `bin/console debug:container MessageBusInterface` which hopefully return a list of service aliases providing that interface... or maybe you have to look through the complete list ...

(**update**: as Snek correctly pointed out in chat, the value must be a FQCN, leading to my assumption that the key should be interface + varname and the values just the interface)

For further usage of the `ServiceSubscriberInterface`, you still need to get a service locator into your class (as hinted [in the comment](https://github.com/symfony/contracts/blob/master/Service/ServiceSubscriberInterface.php)), to then be able to serve the services. However, I wonder if the messenger component would not provide a similar method of retrieving a specific bus by name ...